# Visual Studio 2008: temp files are visible and not removed

Tags: visual-studio

don't know how to describe this behaviour, but recently I see that VS 2008 is creating files like vs~123.tmp etc, for files I modify. However, these files are visible in the solution. It this some kind of option I can enable or disable. Or set something so these files are not visible in the solution. It's a kind of annoying see you solution growing day by day.

I can't find anything on the inet about this.

Answer (score 2):

finaly I found that this is caused by the virus scanner (I started to use MS Essentials as my scanner). Using MS Essentials is the cause of these file stay in my project. By excluding my project-folder to scan for viruses solves the problem.

thanks for the reply Jan